# Find an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the linear operator

\begin{align*}
L : \mathbb{R}^2 & \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \\
& \mapsto
A \cdot v
\end{align*}
on $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by the matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 \\ 1 & - 2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Define now the inner product
$$
\left\langle \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix} ,  \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} \right\rangle = 2\alpha a + k \beta b
$$
where $k >0$ such that L is self-adjoint.

I then have to prove that L is orthonormal diagonalizable and determine a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ of eigenvectors in regards to the above inner product.

I know that L is diagonalizable from spectral theorem and then to determine the orthonormal basis I have calculated the eigenvectors to be $v_1 = (5,1)^T$, $v_2 = (-1,1)^T$. Now I thought about using the Gram Schmidt algorithm but if I do so I get the wrong result.

My professor has provided the answers and he just calculates $||v_1|| = \sqrt{60}$ and $||v_2|| = \sqrt{12}$ and says now that the orthonormal basis is
$$
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{60}} (5,1)^T, \frac{1}{\sqrt{12}} (-1,1)^T\right)
$$
but I do not understand why. Do you mind explaining?

Comment: Maybe is because you applied Gram-Schmidt with respect to the standard scalar product, while you have just introduced another one. Let me know

Comment: Do you not understand why the eigenvectors should be orthogonal, or do you not understand the normalization?

Comment: I found my mistake. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Let $v_1 = (\alpha, \beta)$ and $v_2 = (a, b)$ be your vectors above. To have $L$ self-adjoint we must have $$\langle v_1, Av_2\rangle = \langle Av_1, v_2\rangle $$
i.e., we must have
$$\langle (\alpha, \beta),  (2a+5b, a-2b) \rangle = \langle ( 2\alpha+5\beta, \alpha-2\beta), (a,b)\rangle$$
i.e., we must have
$$2\alpha(2a+5b)+k\beta(a-2b)=2a(2\alpha+5\beta)+kb(\alpha-2\beta)$$
which we can solve for $k = 10$.

At this point we can directly calculate $\langle (5,1), (-1,1)\rangle = -10+10 = 0$ so the given eigenvectors are orthogonal so we are done after normalizing like your professor.